# PHP Getting First Element Of Associative Array

Tags: php

I have this array :

```
$fr_coin_multiplier_asc = array('BTC'=>30, 
                                'ETH'=>28, 
                                'BNB'=>36, 
                                'USDT'=>39,
                                'NEO'=>8, 
                                'LTC'=>9, 
                                'BCC'=>17);
asort($fr_coin_multiplier_asc);
```

and I want to get the first element of that array after sorted using this method :

```
reset($fr_coin_multiplier_asc);
print_r(current($fr_coin_multiplier_asc));
```

in this case, i'm expecting `NEO` and `8` as result, but it only gives me `8`. how to get `NEO` and also `8`?

thank you

Comment: Use `key($array)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `key($fr_coin_multiplier_asc)`. Per the PHP documentation:

> `key()` returns the index element of the current array position.

Answer (score 1):

Modern answer (PHP >= 7.3):

`array[ array_key_first( $array ) ]`

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this construction

```
key($fr_coin_multiplier_asc) . ' => ' . current($fr_coin_multiplier_asc);
```

It return key and value from array. Hope it's help for you

Answer (score 0):

Here we try to display the array content after the sorting, but we break after we get the first one !

```
$fr_coin_multiplier_asc = array('BTC'=>30, 
                                'ETH'=>28, 
                                'BNB'=>36, 
                                'USDT'=>39,
                                'NEO'=>8, 
                                'LTC'=>9, 
                                'BCC'=>17);
asort($fr_coin_multiplier_asc);
reset($fr_coin_multiplier_asc);
print_r(current($fr_coin_multiplier_asc));
echo "<br>";
foreach($fr_coin_multiplier_asc as $x => $x_value) {
    echo $x.":".$x_value;
    break;  
}
```

In this case the output will be : NEO:8

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.4+ (but might cause an index error if empty so I use the fallback ??):

```
\array_values($array)[0] ?? null;
```